# V8 c++ and JS : How to share objects between contexts

Tags: v8

i'm looking for a method/solution for sharing js objects declared into a context (i.e. context A) into another context (i.e. Context B). Both are in the same isolate.
In detail: 
I'm using v8 c++ wrapper for make available c++ class (i.e. cppClass) into js code. So, i can call cppClass.myfunction() or cppClass.myProperty directly into js code.

I have an only one isolate, and a main context for loading and running a complex js file (composed by many js files and many objects/functions declared).

Furthermore i have others contexts where other simple js code is running. All contexts are in the same isolate.

Suppose to have an  AObject declared and used in the contextA, which has a property like AObject.foo=10 . I'm wondering if is it possible to access to AObject in the ContextB and read/change AObject.foo property such as :

```
    // JS code in ContextA
    var AObject=new cppClass();
    AOBject.foo=10;
    ...

// JS code in ContextB
    var newvalue=AObject.foo +1; //or something like myWrapMethod.AObject.foo+1;
    Console.Log(" The new value is : " + newvalue );
    // The new value is : 11
```

Can i access to AObject (i.e. call its functions or set its attributes/properties) from ContextB? 
Thank you in advance

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

a possible answer to my question could be the following approach. In c++, suppose to have the following code:

```
   Handle<Context> contextA=myIsolate::GetCurrentContext();
    ... some code
    Handle<Context> contextB=GetMyBContext();
    ... some code

    contextA->Enter(); // change the context to A Context

    auto global_obj = contextA->Global();
    v8::Local<v8::Value> desiredValue = global_obj->Get(String::NewFromUtf8(myIsolate,"AObject"));
    contextA->Exit(); // change the context to B Context
    // Now  AObject can be used also in the context B (another script js)
   myIsolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global()->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(myIsolate, "AObject"), desiredValue ->ToObject());
```

After that, in the js file (related to B context), i can use AObject with the same values it has in AContext.

Hope to be useful.
Kind regards.

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

You should set both Context security tokens to be the same.
Then you can get an object Ref from a Context, and store/use it from the other.

From v8.h header file:

```
  /**
   * Sets the security token for the context.  To access an object in
   * another context, the security tokens must match.
   */
  void SetSecurityToken(Local<Value> token);
```